# Why is the macro calling another macro showing error?

Tags: c

I wrote the following program and surprising it shows a compilation error that

```
'X' undeclared in exapansion of macro.
```

The code in c is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define X (4+Y)
#define Y (X+3)

int main()
{
    printf("ds", "ds");
    printf("%d\n", 4*X+2);
    return 0;
}
```

I accept that this results in a kind of infinite macro replacement, but if that was an error, that should have been a run time error(truly speaking no error at all). Am I correct? If not, please correct me and explain me where I am getting it wrong?

EDIT: I am surprised that the following code however works perfectly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define X (4+Y)
#define Y 4

int main()
{
    printf("ds", "ds");
    printf("%d\n", 4*X+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How would it be a runtime error? In order to compile, the compiler needs to fully expand the macro, but that would be impossible because the macro expands infinitely.

Comment: thats what I am saying in the brackets..

Comment: Why wouldn't your added code compile? There is no recursive expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C preprocessor does not expand a macro while that macro is being expanded (including indirectly through another macro). So in the expansion of `Y` inside the expansion of `X`, the preprocessor leaves `X` as is, and thus you get an undefined variable error.

Not only does this prevent infinite expansion loops, it also provides a useful feature. Suppose, for example, that you want to write a macro which "wraps" an existing function:

```
#define my_function(x, y) do { \
  fputs("Calling my_function\n", stderr); \
  my_function(x, y); \
while(0);
```

The fact that `my_function` is not expanded inside its own expansion makes it possible to wrap the function with a macro with the same name, thereby avoiding source modifications.

---

For any passing language lawyers, the standard specifies (§6.10.3.4/2):

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.

Comment: ya thats correct but why is the macro for Y in expanded in the macro for X...it should have shown Y is undeclared instead.

Comment: ya I got it what you were telling....thanks by the way...you mean to say that  a macro is never expanded it is own macro expansion....like the problem below is the same as mine: #define X(x) : X//error.....am i correct

Comment: @bhushi: `#define X(x) X` will result in an error if `X` is not defined. Of course, your code might have: `int X = 7;` `#define X(x) X` `printf("%d", X(42));`. That would print 7, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Creating .I file of your code in main.c file using **gcc -E -o main.I main.c** then we get a file which contains as below

```
int main()
{
printf("ds", "ds");
printf("%d\n", 4*(4+(X+3))+2);
return 0;
}
```

Hence macros just replaces the value. So in the expansion of Y inside the expansion of X, the preprocessor leaves X as is.
Hence as X is undefined error occurs.